# I don't have any idea if what's wrong

Tags: java, loops, filereader

While running the following java statement

```
        if (padalaAmount >= 1 && padalaAmount <= 500)

            charge = 150;   
            totalPay = padalaAmount + charge;
        else
            if (padalaAmount >= 501 && padalaAmount <= 1000)
            charge = 300;   
            totalPay = padalaAmount + charge;
        else
            if (padalaAmount >= 1001 && padalaAmount <= 5000)
            charge = 400;   
            totalPay = padalaAmount + charge;
        else
            if (padalaAmount >= 5001 && padalaAmount <= 10000)
            charge = 700;   
            totalPay = padalaAmount + charge;
        outFile.printf("%-12s %12-s %d %d %d", firstName, lastName, `padalaAmount, charge, totalPay);`
```

I am getting following compilation errors:

```
at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2547)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2523)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)
at java.io.PrintWriter.format(PrintWriter.java:905)
at java.io.PrintWriter.printf(PrintWriter.java:804)
at Pera.main(Pera.java:59)
```

Please help me. Deadline is on friday. Thank you.

Comment: Add some descrition and full code so we can help.

Comment: At least *looking* at the error message would be a good start.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the minus sign after 12:

```
outFile.printf("%-12s %12s %d %d %d %n", firstName, lastName, padalaAmount, charge, totalPay);
```

Comment: I removed the minus sign after 12 but it gives me error like this: 

'Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatch Exception
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at Pera.main(Pera.java:28)'

Comment: @msteen13 Looks like an other problem. Ask it as a new question and add some more code to it